# I just earned the Notable Question badge for my “closed:off topic” question!

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Well, it seems I’m not the only one who wanted an answer to this question: [Who gains from a persistent "flat Earth" conspiracy?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72957/who-gains-from-a-persistent-flat-earth-conspiracy)
2500 other people did too!

I still think this is a good question for WB. Just sayin’.

Comment: Close voters didn't gave an explanation.

Comment: @Vincent they did. It's off-topic. And now it has a delete vote.

Comment: @Renan oh come on! That’s just spiteful!

Comment: @Renan woa, what is your justification for the deletion of this question ? I have been on this site since the early days and question deletion is extremely rare, reserved for spam or hatespeech mostly. Not being on topic does not justify a deletion, especially when there are already 4 answers.

Comment: @SRM that is so called "meta effect" - if you post about a question on meta, you should *expect* more votes of all kinds. That's why I avoid voting on meta-mentioned questions unless I really feel I have to, I don't want to add too much to that effect.

Comment: @Molot I expected perhaps more downvoting for highlighting it. I didn't expect retribution.

Comment: I thought about this one a long time as I've spent more time on the site and considered other questions. I won't contest the question being closed, but I am voting to undelete it. I hope others will support that action.

Answer (score 3):

Question being closed do not cease to be notable one.

And for closure, it seems it is basically question about current, real situation, and thus not quite on topic here. Even if it is on topic, there are no objective rules to judge answers better or worse, so in its current shape it probably should be closed as primarily opinion based. And it borderlines high concept issue.

Comment: I don't disagree with your comments on the question per se, but I'd also argue that with a voting balance of +6 (at time of writing) and the fact that there are 3 reopen votes against this question (only 2 delete votes so far) that there is at least *some* dissent as to the value of the question. I understand the precedent issue as well but I do wonder if highly popular / high upvote count shouldn't at least be a mitigating factor in people's decision making process. Interested in your thoughts on that.

Comment: @TimBII, I'd like to comment on your observation: A question about how to use a Canon EOS Rebel T7i DSLR camera may have great value and great interest - but it doesn't belong on worldbuilding.SE.  A question that does belong on WB.SE may also be of great interest and value - and yet be too broad or too story-based.  If the VTC rules don't stand independent of popularity (which is usually the measure used to judge "value") then there's no reason to have them.  It's like saying speeding laws in the U.S. should be ignorable if you have a good reason or if everybody agrees to speed.

Comment: @JBH that's actually a good point; I can see that there still needs to be an objective, measurable standard other than 'popularity'. I guess the additional 8+ months on the site since writing the above have refined my perspective somewhat. :)